# Menubar/wingpanel transparency behavior

Tags: wingpanel, menu, dconf, accessibility, desktop-environment

I'm writing about some confusion on my end regarding how Wingpanel transparency works with respect to different backgrounds.

## What I want:

The effect I am going for on my desktop is reflected by the following:

[image]

[image]

As you can observe, the "menubar" area is completely transparent, and the text is appropriately white, since the background is dark. I can't find an example of black text on an appropriately light background, but ideally the effect would be the same - completely transparent bar, and simply appropriately-contrasted text.

## What I am getting:

Currently, I'm getting the following (new?) undesired effect of a "bar" appearing on certain backgrounds:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The first two images are elementary-shipped backgrounds, while the latter two are my own desktop backgrounds I'm trying out.

No matter what image I upload into the system, I can't appear to get the completely transparent menu bar to appear, as seen in the "What I want" section.

My main issue is that there appears to be no obvious rule for when menu bar backgrounds are excluded/included. From the various tests I've been conducting, the behavior seems totally arbitrary.

Ideally, there would be a setting for a totally solid color menubar, a semi-transparent menubar (what I seem to be getting now, which I do not want), and a completely transparent (no background color) menubar, with appropriately contrasted text.

AFAIK there is no dconf settings for what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS SE. I believe question marked as *original* has your answer.

Comment: The new behaviour you describe is a bug that's surfaced as a result of some GNOME components being updated by Ubuntu. The issue has been found and a fix is in the works,whcih will hopefully be available in the next update to wingpanel. See https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/207 and https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/pull/208